# OpenAI Create Transcription with file sending from Nodejs but it's incorrect

Tags: node.js, nestjs, openai-api, openai-whisper

I'm using OpenAI Create Transcription to translate sub from the audio.
So I will upload my audio on Client Web. Then it will send this file to my server.
My server uses Nestjs with Fastify (Fastify Multipart) to get the file. I also use FormData from `form-data` lib to send request to OpenAI API. Here is the code:

```
 const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('model', this._config.audioModel)
    formData.append('language', input.language)
    formData.append('file', data.file.read(), {
      filename: data.filename
    })
    try {
      const result = await axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions', formData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this._config.apiKey}`,
          ...formData.getHeaders()
        }
      })
      return result.data
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('err', error as any)
    }
```

The problem is the output is not correct anymore. I think the audio quality (or something like that) is reduced or missed.
If I use postman to call directly to the OpenAI API. It's correct translation as I expected.
So I have no clue why this happened :( Anyone know or if you're using OpenAI Transcription API in Nodejs. Can you show how do you achieve it.

Thanks in advance